# creating records in a model with multiple foreign keys Django

Tags: python, django

So i have a model with multiple foreign keys fields

```
class Designations(models.Model):
    designation_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    curriculum = models.ForeignKey(Curricula, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staffs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "arc_designations"
        unique_together = ('curriculum', 'role', 'staff')
        verbose_name_plural = "Designations"
        ordering = ['designation_id']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s of %s %s (%s)' % (self.role.role_name,
                                     self.curriculum.course_period.course.course_abbreviation,
                                     self.curriculum.module_period.module.module_abbreviation,
                                     self.staff.staff_full_name)
```

i want to create a record in this model, so how do i do so in a function view

**edit i tried this function but did not work

```
 @require_POST
    def setInstructor(request):
        staff = Staffs.objects.get(admission_number='16259').pk
        role = Roles.objects.get(pk=1).pk
        curriculum = Curricula.objects.get(pk=1).pk
        designation = Designations(staff=staff, role=role, curriculum=curriculum)
        designation.save()

        return redirect('index'))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what do you mean create a record?

Answer (score 0):

To start with it's better if you name your model as *Designation* because you already have `verbose_name_plural` in the `Meta`.

This is how you would add a new designation record.

Inside `views.py`,

```
from my_app.models import Designation

def my_view(request):

    # do some stuff

    designation = Designation.objects.create(
        curriculum = <your_curriculum>,
        role = <your_role>,
        staff = <your_staff>
    )

    # do some other stuff
```

Comment: what if i dont want to specify the designation_id, just autocreate a new instance

Comment: Why do you need a designation_id? Django autogenerates an id field when a new model instance is created.

Comment: But you are right. If you insist on having it. You don't need to specify it. I am making an edit.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@require_POST
def setInstructor(request):
    staff = Staffs.objects.get(admission_number='16259')
    role = Roles.objects.first()
    curriculum = Curricula.objects.first()
    if not role or not curriculum:
        from django.shortcuts import Http404
        raise Http404('role or curriculum not found')
    Designations(staff=staff, role=role, curriculum=curriculum).save()
    return redirect('index')
```